# Which JVM has a full bytecode execution trace?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, trace

I need a full bytecode-level execution trace of the entire Java program.

I found the JVM TI with the SingleStep event which allosw me to WRITE an agent which
will produce the trace. But surely there is a ready-made JVM option somewhere?

Comment: An application can execute billions of instructions per second.  How do you intend to record and analyse this data?

Comment: See comment below.

Originally i was thinking of only tracing specific classes..

But in any case if u remove startup code, memory stalls, i/o and other crap, i think there are plenty of interesting algorithms that will give a trace of 100 millions instructions which is manageable

Answer (score 2):

Use a debug build of the Hotspot JVM and run it with the `-XX:+TraceBytecodes` flag. See [Trace java bytecode stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257504/trace-java-bytecode-stream) for how to build this debug JVM.

Answer (score 0):

A full Java bytecode trace? That sounds incredibly slow. HotSpot does not support this functionality using any options and I think your demands are a little crazy. Perhaps think of an alternate means of achieving your ultimate goal that isn't quite as naive.

Comment: If the tracing can be turned on and off dynamically, then an "interesting" code region will log a few million instructions which is reasonable...

In retrospect, i agree some sort of dynamic control is required.