# Trace java bytecode stream

Tags: java, jvm

I would like to see the current (bytecode) instruction stream of the JVM it is executing. After some googleing, I found that the jvm debug build offers the `-XX:+TraceBytecodes`option (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554542/which-jvm-has-a-full-bytecode-execution-trace)). However, the mentioned link to the hotspot JVM debug build is dead and I could not find a debug build online :/

Is there another way to trace the jvm bytecode stream or can someone point me in the right direction? I'm running 64 bit ubuntu 16.04.

P.S: I know, its going to be painfully slow to print out the complete instruction stream. However, I am curios

Comment: I'm not really I understood: you want to print (in a file or a console) the bytecode that is executed in real time ?

Comment: It does not need to be in real time, but yeah. Thats pretty much what I am aiming for

Comment: fastdebug builds are not published anymore, but the source code is open so you can create one yourself if you want. JDK9's root repository is here http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/. [This readme](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/raw-file/f2bdff2bd261/README-builds.html) is a fine place to start.

Comment: Also, if it is not necessary to see bytecode that is executed in the particular moment then `javap -v MyClassFile.class` should suffice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`-XX:+TraceBytecodes` option is exactly what are you looking for. It is available in debug builds of HotSpot JVM. You can easily build JVM yourself - just HotSpot, not even JDK.

1. Clone hotspot repository from OpenJDK 8 project

   ```
   hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot
   ```
2. Build 'fastdebug' JVM (assuming JDK is already installed at `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102`)

   ```
   cd hotspot/make
   make ALT_BOOTDIR=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102 ARCH_DATA_MODEL=64 fastdebug
   ```

   You may add `HOTSPOT_BUILD_JOBS=N` to run compilation in `N` parallel processes.
3. Run it

   ```
   export ALT_JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102
   ../build/linux/linux_amd64_compiler2/fastdebug/hotspot -XX:+TraceBytecodes MainClass
   ```

Comment: Super interesting answer, thanks! Step 1 and 2 OK. For running, I hit: `Error: Cannot find the java launcher "/java/re/j2se/1.8.0/promoted/latest/binaries/linux-amd64/bin/java"`. Any hint?

Comment: @MartinMonperrus This means `ALT_JAVA_HOME` env variable is not set. You need to set `ALT_JAVA_HOME` or modify path to JDK directly in `build/linux/linux_amd64_compiler2/fastdebug/hotspot` script.

Answer (score 0):

```
can someone point me in the right direction
```

Well I'll try. The only thing I've found is using `jdb`. You'll have to create your own "printer".

Because you're asking this out of curiosity rather than need, I don't think you'll go as far as creatinf an application that does what yout want, but maybe you'll find other ressources that does it (I didn't find any) or at last ease the job .

From what I understand, `jdb` (java debugger) is a CLI program that uses the JDBA (Java Platform Debugger Architecture) and JVM TI (Java Virtual Machine Tooling Interface).

This is a how `jdb` works:

- You compile your code with the `-g` option (not mandatory), start your main class with `jdb` (rather than `java`).
- You can do step by step execution of your code using `step` command in the console, but this might run multiple bytecode instructions (all the ones corresponding to the instruction in the source code)
- You can use `stepi` which only executes one bytecode line.
- You must set a breakpoint to do step by step execution, and the `cont` option will go to the next breakpoint (just like in a IDE).
- The `list` option allows you to see the code around your breakpoint/line (but not the bytecode).
- You can also get the current line number in source file, and in bytecode (with `wherei`, I think).

The other tool is `javap -c` to get readable bytecode (but I think you already knew this).

Now with all these, I guess you see where I'm going. You create an application (java applicaiton, or some shell/dos) that uses `jdb` to do step by step bytecode execution, and you pick the matching line in your bytecode from `javac -p` to print it. Note that I don't know how you should do in multi-threaded environnements. There are also bytecode visualisation tools like ASM or dirtyJOE, but I don't think they offer bytecode debugging option.

I believe the JVM TI is used by IDE's debuggers, and might be more powerfull faster, and complex than jdb.

Some links that might interest you:

- [How to debug bytecode](http://blog.rewolf.pl/blog/?p=786)
- [Basic debugging with jdb](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077445/testing-debugging/debug-with-jdb.html)
- [Jdb commands list](http://cs.smith.edu/~nhowe/112/Lectures/jdb.pdf)
- [Java debugger platform architecture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/)

As for myself, I was also curious on how java debuging (and other stuff) worked, so this was kinda interesting.