# Why does my Oracle JVM create all these objects for a simple 'Hello World' program?

Tags: java, jvm

I was playing around with `jmap` and found that simple "Hello World" Java program creates thousands of objects. Here is truncated list of objects **Oracle JVM update 131** creates on startup:

```
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:           402        4903520  [I
   2:          1621         158344  [C
   3:           455          52056  java.lang.Class
   4:           194          49728  [B
   5:          1263          30312  java.lang.String
   6:           515          26088  [Ljava.lang.Object;
   7:           115           8280  java.lang.reflect.Field
   8:           258           4128  java.lang.Integer
   9:            94           3760  java.lang.ref.SoftReference
  10:           116           3712  java.util.Hashtable$Entry
  11:           126           3024  java.lang.StringBuilder
  12:             8           3008  java.lang.Thread
  13:            74           2576  [Ljava.lang.String;
  14:            61           1952  java.io.File
  15:            38           1824  sun.util.locale.LocaleObjectCache$CacheEntry
  16:            12           1760  [Ljava.util.Hashtable$Entry;
  17:            53           1696  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node
  18:            23           1472  java.net.URL
  19:            14           1120  [S
  20:             2           1064  [Ljava.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
  21:             1           1040  [Ljava.lang.Integer;
  22:            26           1040  java.io.ObjectStreamField
  23:            12           1024  [Ljava.util.HashMap$Node;
  24:            30            960  java.util.HashMap$Node
  25:            20            800  sun.util.locale.BaseLocale$Key
```

I know that the JVM loads classes from JAR files and expect to see `java.lang.Class`, `java.lang.String` and `[Ljava.lang.Object`. 258 `java.lang.Integer` objects are clear tp me too: this is the `Integer` cache.

But `java.lang.reflect.Field`? `Hashtable`? Many `StringBuilder`s? `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`? Where does this come from?

The program is pretty simple:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
        System.in.read();
    }
}
```

JVM details:

```
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: A java.lang.Class has java.lang.Fields, so why wouldn't there be Field instances? Hashtable is used a lot internally in places you wouldn't inutitively expect it. Since the program is so simple, the garbage collector probably hasn't even run once, so you see *every* single object created during VM startup.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can find the answer yourself by running the application with `-XX:+TraceBytecodes` flag.
This flag is available in [debug builds of HotSpot JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257504/trace-java-bytecode-stream/40296353#40296353).

Here is the detailed Flame Graph (clickable SVG) showing the stack traces where the allocated objects come from.

[image: JDK start-up allocation]

In my case the main sources of start-up allocations were

- URLClassLoader and Extension ClassLoader
- Locale cache
- UsageTrackerClient
- [MetaIndex registry](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/5b86f66575b7/src/share/classes/sun/misc/MetaIndex.java#l38)
- System Properties
- Charset initialization

P.S. [The script](https://gist.github.com/apangin/543f365dde05df0085083e82a3284866) used to generate the [Flame Graph](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph) from TraceBytecodes output.

Comment: Wow this is a cool histogram. A bit less informative (but still gives some glue about cause by observing order) is to use `-verbose:class`.

Comment: Thanks again! This answer is much better.

Comment: BTW: I think one reason why the Field constructor does not show up in the ByteCode traces is because they are generated in native code by Class#getDeclaredFields0().

Comment: @eckes This is true. Objects allocated internally by JVM can be traced using JVM TI  [VMObjectAlloc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#VMObjectAlloc) event. I've omitted this for simplicity, since `getDeclaredFields0` already gives an idea where those objects come from.

Comment: I've summarized the ways to trace object allocation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35924300/how-to-intercept-object-creation-in-java-lower-than-user-class-level/35927613#35927613).

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of maintenance data structures. E.g. every initialized JVM has these [system properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties--), which is a subtype of `Hashtable`, hence, explains the `Hashtable.Entry` instances.

Also, core classes like `java.lang.Character` know the Unicode properties of all characters, also, you see `Locale`-specific classes in you stats, as these have to be properly initialized at startup. What makes these examples so interesting, is, that they are loading these information from files or embedded resources, so their initialization involves I/O and caching mechanisms, whose artifacts you see in your output.

Also, other objects created during the startup process might not have been garbage collected yet. There are a lot of operations, like processing the class path and the jar files specified by it or parsing the command line options, which are more complex than the “Hello World” program that will be executed at the end. Mind that you can create a heap dump instead of just a histogram, so you can see who is holding a reference to the existing objects.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't Hashtable outdated dozens of years ago :)? I wonder why it is still used?

Comment: That’s compatibility. `System.getProperties()` has been declared with a return type of `java.util.Properties`, which is a subclass of `java.util.Hashtable`. Neither, the return type nor the class hierarchy, can be changed without breaking backwards compatibility. It’s not the only place with such a legacy.

Comment: Your point about `jmap` is strange. Only client side of `jmap` is implemented in Java - it runs in a different process and does not affect classes loaded in the target JVM. On the target side it uses AttachListener / DiagnosticCommand APIs of HotSpot JVM. The code which collects and prints the class histogram is written in C++ and does not create a single Java object.

Comment: The attach machinery starts an RMI thread to trigger the heapdump. But instead of causing a OOM you can also use local JMX into the HotSpot management bean to avoid the attach. Or you can run jmap on a system core file if you want to even avoid that.

Comment: @eckes [Dynamic Attach Mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140182/running-jmap-getting-unable-to-open-socket-file/35963059#35963059) is a built-in JVM feature, it has nothing to do with RMI.

Comment: Yes attach API is VM native, but it can be used to load Java agents (and start the JMX RMIConnector like `jcmd <pid> ManagementAgent.start_local`). But you are right `jstack` does not do that. (Must have confused it with `jvisualvm` which does it for displaying the stats). BTW when `jstack -F` or mixed stacks with `-m` are requested `jstack` will use the SA service agent not the VM method (but that does not load classes either).

Comment: @apangin: I used JVisualVM for getting a heap dump and know for sure that it loads a JMX agent on the target side. Since the dump stats looked identical, I assumed that `jmap` does similar. But I also mentioned the possible side effect of a garbage collection on the result, e.g. that the many `Field` instances are gone. Your graphic is great, but it doesn’t help me much finding out where these >8000 `Field` instances came from…

Comment: @eckes: I can avoid the attach by using a local JMX bean, but that may still load JMX related classes which weren’t loaded in an ordinary startup. By the way, you’re mixing up `jmap` and `jstack`.

Comment: @Holger >8000 bytes, not instances. There are only ~100 instances of `Field`, and all their origins do present in the flamegraph (look for `java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields`). Here is a [text source](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/apangin/543f365dde05df0085083e82a3284866/raw/acc8ab3bc4d64a96999f80bf85e9216ae2550f99/SampleFlamegraph.txt) of the flamegraph for convenience.

Comment: @apangin: right, >100, not >8000 instance. I knew that before I wrote the comment, but got confused while writing. Thanks for the correction and for the text source.

Answer (score 2):

**Checking if tools load additional classes**

I tried the following program:

```
package test;
public class MainSleep {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (MainSleep.class) {
            MainSleep.class.wait(5*1000);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it with:

```
"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java" \
  -verbose:class -cp target\classes test.MainSleep
```

I get verbose class loading messages, then a 5 sec pause and then the shutdown does load even more classes:

```
...
[Loaded sun.misc.PerfCounter from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.misc.Perf$GetPerfAction from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.misc.Perf from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.misc.PerfCounter$CoreCounters from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.nio.MappedByteBuffer from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.nio.DirectByteBuffer from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.nio.LongBuffer from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.nio.DirectLongBufferU from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.security.PermissionCollection from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.security.Permissions from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.net.URLConnection from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.net.www.URLConnection from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.net.www.MessageHeader from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.io.FilePermission from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.io.FilePermission$1 from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.io.FilePermissionCollection from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.security.AllPermission from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.security.UnresolvedPermission from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.security.BasicPermissionCollection from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded test.MainSleep from file:/D:/ws/BIS65/test-java8/target/classes/]
[Loaded sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Class$MethodArray from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Void from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
...
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown$Lock from c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar]
```

So this would be the baseline. When I now use `jstack` or `jmap` on that file and check for verbose class loading messages I can see if it introduces new classes (not sure about instances of course).

With `jstack -l` and `jstack`, the following additional one class is loaded:

```
[Loaded java.lang.Class$MethodArray from
[Loaded java.lang.Void from
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractOwnableSynchronizer ...
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown from
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown$Lock from
```

With `jstack -F` or `jstack -m` no(!) additional class is loaded:

```
[Loaded java.lang.Class$MethodArray from
[Loaded java.lang.Void from
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown from
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown$Lock from
```

None of `jmap` `-clstat`,`-finalizerinfo`,`-heap`, `-histo` or `-histo:live` loaded additional classes:

```
[Loaded java.lang.Class$MethodArray from
[Loaded java.lang.Void from
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown from
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown$Lock from
```

The same is true for `jmap -dump:format=b,file=ignore.hprof` with and without the -F option as well as with and without the `live` flag.

Just for completeness, if I use *jvisualvm* or *jconsole* it will always trigger a lot of JMX class loads for thread, heap and application snapshots. Most likely because it always opens the dashboard for the process.

**Exploring Heap Content**

So now that we have established this I took a look at the `jmap -dump:format=b` (non-live, non-forced) heap dump with MAT, looking for the Fields you have been interested in:

The MAT **unreachable objects histogram** (which shows instances found in the heap but not connected to any GC root, which is basically all not-yet collected garbage) has 3038 objects, and the top 10:

```
Class Name                               | Objects | Shallow Heap
------------------------------------------------------------------
char[]                                   |   1.026 |      113.848
java.lang.String                         |     599 |       14.376
int[]                                    |     423 |        7.664
java.lang.Object[]                       |     220 |       14.192
java.lang.StringBuilder                  |     137 |        3.288
java.lang.reflect.Field                  |     115 |        8.280
java.lang.ProcessEnvironment$CheckedEntry|      66 |        1.056
java.io.File                             |      59 |        1.888
java.lang.Class                          |      32 |            0
java.lang.StringBuffer                   |      30 |          720
```

There is currently no single live `Field` instance visible with MAT and only very limited of `Class` instances. This looks much like a .hprof or MAT problem: the Class instances seems to not show any of their fields in the heap dump. I think they should be softly(!) referenced by `Class#reflectionData : SoftReference<ReflectionData<T>>`, but I think this should be visible in the heap dump and not losing 115 fields. (There is no `Class$ReflectionData` in the live heap and 14 `Class$ReflectionData` in the unreachable histo. That can fit well with 115 Fields.

*(I guess I will check back with Serviceability-dev@openjdk on that. This does not fit in a comment, so this is an incomplete answer but I intend to enhance it).*

Comment: That’s indeed very interesting. Perhaps, it is connected to the fact that it only reports 32 `java.lang.Class` instances instead of >400…

Comment: Started Thread here: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/serviceability-dev/2017-June/021413.html