# Printing backtraces when debugging java

Tags: java, linux, jvm

I'm investigating frequent invokation of `futex` syscall in the application that is transferring data from files to a socket that `perf record` shows.

I tried to attach to jvm with gdb and set catch point on futex syscall and then print `backtrace`s to understand where it comes from. The problem was that `bt` fails with some internal error:

`gdb -p <jvm_pid>`

```
(gdb) catch syscall futex
Catchpoint 1 (syscall 'futex' [202])
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Thread 2 "java" received signal SIGSTOP, Stopped (signal).
[Switching to Thread 0x7fa60385c700 (LWP 27739)]
0x00007fa602a0e9f3 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) backtrace
/build/gdb-GT4MLW/gdb-8.1/gdb/frame.c:534: internal-error: frame_id get_frame_id(frame_info*): Assertion `fi->level == 0' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
```

So eventually I got the following:

```
Python Exception <class 'KeyboardInterrupt'> Quit: 
#0  0x00007fa602a0e9f3 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fa60236e9bb in os::PlatformEvent::park (this=0x7fa5fc018200) at ./src/hotspot/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp:5987
```

which looks incomplete. Is gdb complaining about dynamic code generation so this might not be possible to trace such things with it?

I tried to print backtrace immediately after attaching and it worked fine:

`gdp -p <jvm pid>`

```
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
0x00007fa602a09d2d in __pthread_timedjoin_ex () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
Installing openjdk unwinder
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fa602a09d2d in __pthread_timedjoin_ex () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fa60343a91d in ContinueInNewThread0 (continuation=continuation@entry=0x7fa603434c50 <JavaMain>, stack_size=1048576, args=args@entry=0x7ffd45c7ec50) at ./src/jdk/src/solaris/bin/java_md_solinux.c:1056
#2  0x00007fa603436b1a in ContinueInNewThread (ifn=ifn@entry=0x7ffd45c7ed70, threadStackSize=<optimized out>, argc=<optimized out>, argv=0x556124e8f600, mode=mode@entry=0, what=what@entry=0x0, ret=0)
    at ./src/jdk/src/share/bin/java.c:2037
#3  0x00007fa60343a9eb in JVMInit (ifn=ifn@entry=0x7ffd45c7ed70, threadStackSize=<optimized out>, argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>, mode=0, mode@entry=1, what=0x0, 
    what@entry=0x7ffd45c83c8c "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.Main", ret=<optimized out>) at ./src/jdk/src/solaris/bin/java_md_solinux.c:1103
#4  0x00007fa603437267 in JLI_Launch (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>, jargc=<optimized out>, jargv=<optimized out>, appclassc=1, appclassv=0x0, fullversion=0x55612461e848 "1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-b12", dotversion=0x55612461e841 "1.8", pname=0x55612461e83c "java", lname=0x55612461e834 "openjdk", javaargs=0 '\000', cpwildcard=1 '\001', javaw=0 '\000', ergo=0)
    at ./src/jdk/src/share/bin/java.c:304
#5  0x000055612461e691 in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at ./src/jdk/src/share/bin/main.c:125
```

So is the problem with dynamic code generation? Maybe there is a workaround?

Comment: It's not easy to traverse Java stack at any arbitrary point - I'm pretty sure gdb unwinder does not handle all possible situations. I'd recommend using debug or fastdebug build of JVM - it has some useful helper functions specially for debugging purposes, e.g. calling `p ps()` from gdb will print Java stack of the current thread.

Comment: @apangin Can you give an idea of where to get such debug/fastdebug builds? Or should I have to compile it myself?

Comment: I know [builds.shipilev.net](https://builds.shipilev.net/) has some. But it's also quite easy to compile them yourself, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40296353/3448419).